# How to find daily/weekly data on the state of the economy

Tags: macroeconomics

I am interested in economic modelling of the correct state of the economy.  Figures such as unemployment and gdp come out with a considerable delay.  What are good publicly available datasets that are available daily/weekly that are known to be proxies for unemployment and gdp growth?

Ideally these data would be available for a number of countries. I am only interested in datasets I can download in full.

Comment: There are surveys of company intentions and perceptions (production, sales, recruitment) which have a weak relationship to GDP and unemployment but they are often produced privately for a fee with a public press release so are not so easily available

Comment: (1) Financial markets are sensitive to the economy. (2) Read the financial news, real-time data are extremely popular. However, many sources are unlikely to be free.

Comment: BrianRomanchuk I don't think the Dow Jones , for example, is a good predictor of GDP. It's all about how much much big companies can make.

Answer (score 2):

That frequency is very hard to come by for GDP and employment, especially in many countries.

The only thing I know that allows that level of measurement is prices: check https://www.pricestats.com/ for daily measures of inflation, purchasing power parity and real exchange rate. It's available for many countries, both in developed and emerging economies.

Comment: Can that data be downloaded as a csv file?

Comment: I downloaded their daily inflation in CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

Trading Economics https://tradingeconomics.com/ has copious data on various markets for various countries and has tools for downloading datasets in full as well as dashboards for analyzing trends on the site.

It seems like it has most everything you would be looking for and is updated quite regularly

Hope this helps! Good luck :)

EDIT: As a possible supplement, The Penn World Tables https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/productivity/pwt/?lang=en, although only up until 2017, have great international data for further insight!

Answer (score 1):

Check this resource https://fred.stlouisfed.org/, I think is one of the best free repository for economic data.
It includes gdp growth and unemployment for many different countries (at monthly or quaterly frequency, which I think is the best you can find with this kind of data)

Comment: Does it offer CSV download?

Comment: Sure, you can choose between .csv or .xls (excel format)